# Modify URL for Gatsby Contentful blog posts

Tags: gatsby, contentful

I recently integrated Contentful with my Gatsby site and everything is mostly working perfectly.
I am having one final issue which is around the slugs/URLs for my blog post pages.

Currently the URL for these is something like http://localhost:8000/blog/another-blog-post but I am wanting them to be http://localhost:8000/blog/year/another-blog-post with the year being created based on their published date.

In my gatsby-node.js file I have the following

```
if (posts.length > 0) {
    posts.forEach((post, index) => {
      const previousPostId = post.previous?.id 
      const nextPostId = post.next?.id 
      const postYear = new Date(post.node.publishDate).getFullYear();

      createPage({
        path: `/blog/${post.node.slug}`,
        component: blogPost,
        context: {
          id: post.id,
          previousPostId,
          nextPostId,
          slug: post.node.slug
        },
      })
    })
  }
```

In that example `post.node.slug` is 'another-blog-post'
I have created the `postYear` variable which is correctly giving me the year they were published.
I think link to those posts with `<Link className="button" aria-label={`Read ${title}`} to={`/blog/${post.slug}`} itemProp="url">`

I can't figure out how to get the URL to actually include the year.

I did try changing the `path`, `slug` and `to=` to include `${postYear}` but that leads to a 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my own question, not 100% sure if this is the best way to do it but it seems to work quite well.
I updated the path to be `path: /blog/${postYear}/${post.node.slug}` and then linked to it with

```
const postUrl = `/blog/${post.postYear}/${post.slug}`
<Link className="button" aria-label={`Read ${title}`} to={postUrl} itemProp="url">
```

Tested with a variety of years and seems to be doing what I would expect.